# How to update SeekBar from MediaPlayer running in Service?

Tags: android, service, media-player, android-seekbar

In my app i maid a MediaPlayer playing from Service, to update SeekBar
i maid a timer task in Service

```
timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new RemindTask(), 0, 1 * 1000);

class RemindTask extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (mediaPlayer!=null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
           MusicPlayerActivity.progress=mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
           MusicPlayerActivity.total=mediaPlayer.getDuration();
        }
    }
}
```

and using runnable list i made a run method in activity page,

```
@Override
public void run()
{
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            seekBar.setMax(total);
            seekBar.setProgress(progress);
        }
    });
}
```

But my issue is that app is very much slow and going stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use bound service if you need service to activity communication
[check it here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Binder). Or use libraries like [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)

Answer (score 4):

use `BroadcastReceiver` to update seek-bar form service to activity

add broadcast in activity to update your seek bar

```
BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //do something based on the intent's action
            // UPDATE YOUR UI FROM HERE
        }
    };
```

register receiver in activity like below

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }
```

send broadcast from your service -> add below code in your service to call broadcast

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("android.mybroadcast");
this.context.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

pass data in intent -> integer value for seek-bar :)

Answer (score 1):

Put in Service to update the value of seek variable(global and static variable)

```
     private final Handler handler = new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg){


      //  update the seek variable here
        }
    };
```

In your activity:

```
        PlayerConstants.PROGRESSBAR_HANDLER = new Handler(){
             @Override
              public void handleMessage(Message msg){
//get seek bar variable value and set to progress bar
}
        };
     }catch(Exception e){}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can find a working solution in the android-UniversalMusicPlayer reference implementation in https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer/blob/master/mobile/src/main/java/com/example/android/uamp/ui/FullScreenPlayerActivity.java.

The concept involves setting the current position on a MediaSession instance and then polling the MediaController for changes + calculating the current position:

```
private void updateProgress() {
    if (mLastPlaybackState == null) {
        return;
    }
    long currentPosition = mLastPlaybackState.getPosition();
    if (mLastPlaybackState.getState() != PlaybackState.STATE_PAUSED) {
        // Calculate the elapsed time between the last position update and now and unless
        // paused, we can assume (delta * speed) + current position is approximately the
        // latest position. This ensure that we do not repeatedly call the getPlaybackState()
        // on MediaController.
        long timeDelta = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() -
                mLastPlaybackState.getLastPositionUpdateTime();
        currentPosition += (int) timeDelta * mLastPlaybackState.getPlaybackSpeed();
    }
    mSeekbar.setProgress((int) currentPosition);
}
```

Comment: He was asking how to update from a `Service` where you don't have direct access to the `MediaPlayer` object in the `Activity`.

Comment: @KrisB Don't get why people downvoted.. The whole point of the background service is that it HAS access to the MediaPlayer. Please read the docs and examples again to make sure you understand the concepts. The media session is used to update metadata related to the playback state from the service. All activities can then access the media session and accordingly update the UI. The example I posted comes from Google - the same folks that created Android. They should know how to build a media player app